# Marking angles in a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have TikZ draw a triangle on the Cartesian plane - a triangle with vertices at the origin O, A = (2,1), and B = (-3, 5).  I would also like to have two angles drawn and labeled - one from the positive x-axis to OA and one from the positive x-axis to OB.  I would like the angles to have arrows where they touch OA and OB. I would also like to keep "\documentclass{amsart}" in the preamble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two simple possibilities using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

1. For version 3.0, using the `angles` and `quotes` libraries:

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

   \tikzset{
   mydot/.style={
     fill,
     circle,
     inner sep=1.5pt
     }
   }

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
   % the coordinates of the vertices
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (A) at (2,1);
   \coordinate (B) at (-3,5);
   \coordinate (E) at (2,0);

   % the axis
   \draw[help lines,->] (-3.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
   \draw[help lines,->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.5);

   % the edges of the triangle    
   \draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;

   % labelling the vertices
   \node[mydot,label={right:$A$}] at (A) {};
   \node[mydot,label={left:$B$}] at (B) {};
   \node[mydot,label={below:$O$}] at (O) {};

   % the arcs for the angles
   \path[gray]
     pic["$\alpha$" shift={(23pt,3pt)},draw,->,angle radius=1.5cm] {angle = E--O--A}
     pic["$\beta$" above=6pt,draw,->,angle radius=0.75cm] {angle = E--O--B};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. For version 2.10, without libraries and using the `arc` path:

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{tikz}

   \tikzset{
   mydot/.style={
     fill,
     circle,
     inner sep=1.5pt
     }
   }

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
   % the coordinates of the vertices
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (A) at (2,1);
   \coordinate (B) at (-3,5);

   % the axis
   \draw[help lines,->] (-3.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
   \draw[help lines,->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.5);

   % the edges of the triangle    
   \draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;

   % labelling the vertices
   \node[mydot,label={right:$A$}] at (A) {};
   \node[mydot,label={left:$B$}] at (B) {};
   \node[mydot,label={below:$O$}] at (O) {};

   % the arcs for the angles    
   \begin{scope}[gray]
   \draw[->] 
     (1,0) +(0:0.5cm) arc [radius=1cm,start angle=0,end angle=41] node[midway,right] {$\alpha$};
   \draw[->] 
     (0.5,0) +(0:0.25cm) arc [radius=0.75cm,start angle=0,end angle=122] node[midway,above] {$\beta$};
   \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: we have angles lib for that now on version 3.00 ;)

Comment: @percusse really useful library. I've updated my answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Both graphs look nice!  I have just been told about TikZ and have not found anything on a web site to explain the syntax.  I would like to ask you some questions about your code.    What does the following code in the preamble tell LaTeX.  What is "mydot/.sty" and "fill,"\tikzset{
mydot/.style={
  fill,
  circle,
  inner sep=1.5pt
  }
}

Comment: @user143462 `mydot/.style` declares a node style; the style is given as `fill,
  circle,
  inner sep=1.5pt` which means the node has `circle` shape, it is filled (with the default color which is black) and has an inner separation of `1.5pt` (this is to control the size). A detailed explanation, in the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). The manual is really comprehensive and has a lot of examples.

Comment: @user143462 Also, don't forget that you can accept answers by clicking the checkmark to their left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: I see some explanation on page 50 of PGF manual. I will look later. In your code, you have "\coordinate (0) at (0,0);". Is this "declaring a variable" called O. You subsequently have "\draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;" and "\node[mydot,label={below:$O$}] at (O) {};" that seems to tell TikZ what to draw regarding the point O. Why do you need "mydot" in the optional argument for \node?  In the command "\draw[->] (1,0) +(0:0.5cm) arc [radius=1cm ...]{$\alpha$}", what does "(1,0) +(0:0.5cm)" tell TikZ to draw. Is (1,0) the point arc starts? What is "+"? Why is there a colon in "(0:0.5cm)"? Thanks.

Comment: @user143462 all your questions can be answered by reading the PGF manual.

Comment: I looked in the manual.  If the manual answers these questions, tell me the page at which to look.  I have asked this same question to a friend who has used TikZ for awhile.  He didn't know.

Comment: @user143462 I don't see *one* question; I see five of them :) the `mydot` in the options of a node simply makes the node adopt the style that I previously defined for `mydot` (the node will be a filled circle of `3pt` diameter). So, for example, `\node[mydot,label={below:$O$}] at (O) {};` draws a small filled circle at the coordinate given by `(O)` (previusly defined to be at `(0,0)`) and places the label `$O$` below the `(O)` coordinate. I'll continue in another comment (almost reached the word limit for this one).

Comment: `(1,0) +(0:0.5cm)` doesn't draw anything; it is the `arc` path which will do the drawing; a coordinate specified with a colon, uses polar coordinates: `(<angle>:<length>)`, so `(0:0.5)` means `0.5` units at `0` degrees. Now, `(1,0) +(0:0.5)` is roughly equivalent to "move to `(1,0)` and then, from this point move `0.5` units in the direction given by `0` degrees" (see page 38 of the PGF manual for version 3.0 for a detailed explanation of the `+` and `++` modifiers). (continued)

Comment: @user143462  basically, `(1,0) +(0:0.5)` could be replaced by `(1.5,0)` I used the apparently more complex form just to have a better control over the drawing of the arc.

Comment: I hope my previous comments answer your questions regarding the code in my exmaple.